# Interpolating data which arent in the proper list form

Tags: list-manipulation, interpolation

I have some data which are structured poorly, and I want to interpolate them. This is the way they are structured:

```
{{z1_1,z1_2,....z1_21}, {z2_1,z2_2,....z2_21}, ....{z11_1,z_11_2, ....z11_21}}
```

And then I have separate arrays which contain the x and y data.
`{x1,x2, ....x11}`
And
`{y1,y2, ....y21}`

If I understand the interpolation function correctly, then the data for interpolation should be structured like this:

```
{{{x1,y1},z1_1},{{x1,y2},z1_2}, ....{{x11,y21},z11_21}}
```

Unfortunately, I have no clue how to re-structure the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll set the bar very low to start this

```
x={x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,x9,x10,x11};
y={y1,y2,y3,y4,y5,y6,y7,y8,y9,y10,y11,y12,y13,y14,y15,y16,y17,y18,y19,y20,y21};
z=Table[21*(i-1)+j,{i,11},{j,21}];
result={};
For[xi=1,xi<=11,xi++,
 For[yi=1,yi<=21,yi++,
  AppendTo[result,{x[[xi]],y[[yi]],z[[xi,yi]]}]
  ]];
result
```

Now we just need 8 more increasingly impressive, increasingly unimaginable completely different ways of doing this

Answer (score 1):

As an example:

```
xlist = "x" <> ToString@# & /@ Range[11];
ylist = "y" <> ToString@# & /@ Range[21];
zlist = Table["z" <> ToString@i <> ToString@j, {i, 1, 11}, {j, 1, 21}];

data = Thread[{Outer[List, xlist, ylist], zlist}] // Map[Transpose]
```

You can `Flatten` it if required. Add `// Flatten[#, 1] &` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

```
MapThread[List/*Transpose/*Splice, {Outer[List, xs, ys], zs}]
```

or

```
Flatten[MapThread[List, {Outer[List, xs, ys], zs}, 2], 1]
```

Where `xs` is your list of 11 x coords, `ys` is your list of 21 y coords, and `zs` is your 11 by 21 array of z values.

Riffing on Bill's solution:

```
Flatten[
  Table[
    {{xs[[xidx]], ys[[yidx]]}, zs[[xidx, yidx]]}, 
    {xidx, xCount}, 
    {yidx, yCount}], 
  1]
```

Where I've abstracted out the dimensions. In your specific case `xCount` would be 11 and `yCount` would be 21.